# Shell script to move and retype files

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to create a way that I can run a single line of code to move and rename files.

My current structure.

`src/component/fb/*.js`

the destination and format I want them moved into:

`public/api/*.txt`

**example: test.js become test.txt**

Answer (score 1):

Written out as four lines:

```
for i in src/component/fb/*.js; do
  i_basename=${i##*/}
  mv -- "$i" "public/api/${i_basename%.js}.txt"
done
```

...or as one:

```
for i in src/component/fb/*.js; do i_basename=${i##*/}; mv -- "$i" "public/api/${i_basename%.js}.txt"; done
```

Comment: nice one, +1 for `${i##*/}` instead of `$(basename $i)`. In my thinking, I initially dismissed a string replacement approach, in the fear that some perverted mind might want to create a file with a `'/'` in the name, but it seems that it's usually disallowed (based on the small size sampling I did on a few systems).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** If you use `zsh`, you can say:

```sh
for i in src/component/fb/*.js; do mv "$i" "public/api/$(basename $i:r.txt)"; done
```

@CharlesDuffy's answer is better though. As he commented below, `basename` is a command (whereas `${i##*/}` is a built-in substitution via pattern matching).

Comment: So this is working only its saving the files like this: 

FbButtonCircle.js:r.txt 

I wanted it to save them like this: 

FbButtonCircle.txt 

Any idea?

Comment: I think Pierre meant to write `"public/api/$(basename "${i%.js}.txt")"`. Not that I recommend that; `basename` being an external command, it's slow to run, so a very bad idea to use in a loop. This command will spend almost as much time calculating `basename`s as it does doing `mv`s.

Comment: oh, sorry, I use `zsh`; thought `${i:r}` was standard.